Error when importing Rasterio to AWS Lambda
I'm trying to use a rasterio layer in my lambda function but when I try to import rasterio in the code it throws this exception in cloudwatch:
[ERROR] AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import\
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load\
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked\
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked\
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module\
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed\
File "/var/task/sentinel.py", line 3, in <module> import rasterio

I'm using a python 3.10 environment to create the layer in windows, any ideas what might be causing this?

Not an answer but given that (1) you're building in Windows and (2) the library is looking for Windows specific files (DLL's) I'd guess that the native layer under this library requires you to build for Linux which is what Lambda runs.

that was it lol built it using the WSL and it worked, thanks
